# What does it mean by “I’m happier than in a long time”?

Tags: meaning

What does it mean by “I’m happier than I’ve been in a long time”?
Does it mean I’m “happier” than ever(like the happiest in my life) or “as happy as” before?

Answer (score 1):

That expression means that they are more happy than they have been for a certain period of time, indicating that at one point in time they were as happy or more happy than they were now. Consider this example:

> Ten years ago I lost my job and the past few years were rough. However, I got a new job, one I really like. I'm happier than I've been in a long time.

Comment: Though OP has a point here. I'm not aware of people who accurately measure happiness coefficients, so there's not much difference between most people's "I'm happier than I've been in a long time" and "I can't remember a time when I was happier".